# Why is xml-to-json function returning exponential notation?

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xslt-3.0, xml-to-json

All of my XSLT is working when using the `xml-to-json()` function except for this part,

```
<number key="send_at">
    <xsl:text>1615842000</xsl:text>
</number>
```

which returns

```
"send_at":1.615842E9
```

when I intend to get this result:

```
"send_at":1615842000
```

Comment: Thank you, @jag959.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### XPath 3.1 <sup><sub><sub>(current)</sub></sub></sup>

Converting numbers to exponential notation is correct according to the spec ([XPath and XQuery Functions and Operators 3.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/)):

> [**17.5.4 fn:xml-to-json**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-xml-to-json)
>
> **Rules**
>
> Nodes in the input tree are handled by applying the following rules,
> recursively.
>
> 4. An element `$E` named number results in the output of the string result of `xs:string(xs:double(fn:string($E)))`

The `fn:xml-to-json` function does allow an `$options` argument, which provides a means for implementation-dependent extensions.  Saxon 10.5 already leverages this mechanism to support passing through the value, without regard to JSON validity: <sup>1</sup>

```
map{'number-formatter':function($x){$x}}
```

### XPath 4 <sup><sub><sub>(upcoming)</sub></sub></sup>

A formatter is an officially supported option to `fn:xml-to-json` [planned for XPath 4](https://qt4cg.org/branch/master/xpath-functions-40/Overview-diff.html#func-xml-to-json): <sup>2</sup>

> `number-formatter`:   Determines how numeric values should be formatted.
>
> - **Type**: `(function(xs:string) as xs:string)?`
> - **Default**: `()`

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Thanks to Michael Kay for noting this mechanism (and foreseeing its need (and already implementing it in Saxon 10.5)).</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> Thanks to Martin Honnen for noting this XPath 4 update.</sub>

Comment: Or you will have to wait for XPath 4 where https://qt4cg.org/branch/master/xpath-functions-40/Overview-diff.html#func-xml-to-json suggests you can insert your own `number-formatter` that "Determines how numeric values should be formatted:" `Type: (function(xs:string) as xs:string)?`

Comment: In fact Saxon 10.5 implements this proposed extension, though it hasn't yet found its way into the documentation. For example you could use `map{'number-formatter':function($x){$x}}` which would output the value as written in the XML (whether or not it is valid in JSON).

Comment: @kjhughes "There does not appear to be any leeway for implementation-specific options". Actually there is. §1.5 of the F+O spec says "It is not an error if the options map contains options with names other than those described in this specification. Implementations may attach an ·implementation-defined· meaning to such entries..."

Comment: @MichaelKay, that's cool, even Saxon HE 10.5 seems to output `xml-to-json(<number xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions'>1234567</number>, map { 'number-formatter' : function($x) { $x } })` as `1234567`.

Comment: @MichaelKay, Martin Honnen:  Excellent.  Answer updated.  Thank you both!